# Local manuals for common rites shradha, aarti etc

Tags: vedas, rites

Is there a manual to perform certain rites described? For eg. for Shraddha or even as simple as an Aarthi, is there step by step approach on how to do this written in the Vedas or adjunct Brahmanas?

Comment: Shraddha - Garuda Purana, grhyasutras. Shraddha kalpa books. Aarti would be in some books not available to the public in general, but you may refer to Gita press nitya Puja Prakash for aarti.

Comment: Some of these rites are tantric in nature - in Vaishnavism, you might find them in Naradapanchratra.

Comment: Manuals are found in every region of Indian in the native languages .. in Hindi language consult the book Nitya Karma Puja Prakash .. if your language is not Hindi you have to find an alternative in your mother tongue .. do not try to follow directly some scriptures as that could be misleading and cumbersome to follow.

Comment: @Rickross Are there translations for Nitya Karma Puja Prakash as Hindi is difficult for me to follow.

Comment: @Adiyarkku:If some of the books are not available to the public in general then how should one be expected to follow certain traditions or daily prayers and practices?

Comment: What is your mother tongue? in every Indian languages such books are available .. I use a Bengali book called Nitya Karma Puja Paddhati which is very similar to Nitya Karma Puja Prakash @mindentropy

Comment: @mindentropy go by what Ross says.

Comment: @Rickross: My mother tongue is Kannada and proficient in English. I also can read and write Hindi and hence can understand it. Nitya Karma Puja Prakash I feel is not descriptive and detailed. I want a detailed manual explaining it like for a student. For eg: It is very difficult to understand the hand position while taking theertha's without a proper diagram or photos.

Comment: Ok let's see what can I find for you @mindentropy